# Facebook - check this post liked or not

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

In application on Android use Android SDK and get all posts of timeline. How can i check liked this post or not? 
To post, you can get all likes. There may be more than 1000 and each time my search Like them - crazy. 
Separate method to get my likes i not found. Bad looking or have a separate method?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is a boolean field to specify whether a user likes a comment, but not an entire post. You'd have to search through the post likes to find the user's id and figure it out that way. Luckily, it's always shown up for me in the first 25 likes in the list so I don't have to do more API calls, but that might be a coincidence.